# How to reference a string in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, function, arraylist

I've been writing a program (a hangman game) today, and have come across a few snags, I know you guys don't like people just using this as answers to their homework, but I have searched quite a while, and while I have posted this program earlier in the development, I have come to new ground. I am getting to grips with lists, tuples, dictionaries, etc. and this program has been great practice. Sorry for the wall of text!

*The Question:*

Is there a way to refer to a string when using a list?

Context - defining a function (last line being a test to see if working)

```
def click_1 (text):
    key_1 = word.index [letter]
    hidden_word[key_1] = letter
    print (hidden_word)
```

This throws up a long error, which I wont post, here is the 'important' part in my eyes:

```
File "/Users/foo/Desktop/Hangman.py", line 19, in click_1
    key_1 = word.index [letter]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

If someone could help me, that would be great. I've tried using the 'in' statement, but I have not been able to make it work - currently, though I suspect it may be part of the solution. I've tried:

```
key_1 = word.index [letter in word]
```

and:

```
key_1 = word.index([letter] in word)
```

both of which do not work.

Cheers in advance from a young programmer!

Comment: I susped `word` is not what you suspect it is. What is the output of `type(word)`  just before the error?

Comment: `key_1 = word.index(letter)`

Comment: @ReutSharabani I don't fully understand your question, but does this: word_list = ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANNANA"]

word = word_list [random.randrange(-1,3)]
hidden_word = ["_"] * len(word)                                    Answer?

Comment: Don't understand the question either.  I see you passing in `text` but not using it in the function.  How are the other variables you do reference generated and what `type` are they?

Comment: It would help if you explained: 1. What type `word` is; 2. what type `letter` is; 3. **exactly** what you want to do with this line of code that you can't get working. It would help to show specific examples of a value for `word`, a value for `letter`, and *exactly* what you want `key_1` to end up being in each case, showing your reasoning. The reason I say this is because as it stands, I have *absolutely no idea* what you're trying to ask. What do you mean by "refer to a string when using a list"? What do you mean by "using a list"? Refer to **what** string?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel   1: word is a random word out of the list word_list. 2: letter is from the string module I imported from a module (I typed import string at the top) 3: i want to get the index of the letter in word that you pressed on the gui I built (using tkinter) and then use that to indicate the index number on the hidden_word list, and replace the  '_' with the letter. key_1 I want to be the number that the index is and use that to change the hidden_word. It currently does not work because I can't use letter to find the correct index for the letter. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what your function is SUPPOSED to do, but here's the issue you're having:

```
def click_1(text):
    key_1 = word.index [letter]
    # word.index(letter) calls the function,
    # word.index[letter] tries to treat the function like a dictionary
    # and pull up its value attached to the key `letter`
    hidden_word[key_1] = letter
    print (hidden_word)
```

Alternatively I'd suggest looking at a different design pattern. Try instead:

```
the_word = generate_random_word_from(word_list)
# which is probably as simple as random.choice(word_list)

guessed_letters = set()

def display_word():
    global the_word
    global guessed_letters
    # globals are bad in practice, but this is actually a great use case
    # for a global if you haven't wrapped this all up in OOP yet!

    masked_list = [letter if letter in guessed_letters else "_" for
                     letter in the_word]
    # this is literally:
    # # masked_list = []
    # # for letter in the_word:
    # #     if letter in guessed_letters:
    # #         masked_list.append(letter)
    # #     else:
    # #         masked_list.append("_")
    masked_word = ''.join(masked_list)
    # join the list on an empty string, e.g.:
    # ['s','_','m','e','w','_','r','d'] becomes 's_mew_rd'
    print(masked_word)
    # this wouldn't be a bad place to trigger your win condition, too.
    # Could be as simple as
    # # if "_" not in masked_word:
    # #     you_win()

def guess_letter():
    global the_word
    global guessed_letters

    guessed_letter = prompt_for_letter_somehow()
    if guessed_letter not in the_word:
        add_hangman_piece() # put another arm/leg/whatever on your dude
    guessed_letters.add(guessed_letter)
        # add that letter to the guessed_letters set anyway
    # validation would be nice here so you can't just keep guessing the same letters
```

Comment: I think passing in word and guessed_letters would  be a better design

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the best design would be to wrap it all in a `class HangmanGame` and letting it modify it that way, but passing in the same two variables every time doesn't really make sense. These really are globals, so treat them as such.

Comment: I don't agree, globals are never a good idea. It is actually pretty simple to create a game without ever needing globals

Comment: @PadraicCunningham to each their own. I avoid `globals` in instances where you shouldn't really be using them, but these truly **are** global variables. Let's call a horse a horse and define it explicitly, rather than passing the same set of arguments to every call of `drive(analog_car)` :)

Comment: While this is a simple case, I'm with @PadraicCunningham since this usually leads to bad design (not extensible, for example), and causes design problems which are a headache later on.

Comment: @ReutSharabani "extensible" in this case meaning...? I feel like that'd be a valid critique if this were the kind of example that leads to extension, but you can't really "extend" a hangman game :) In this case, globals are more than fine: they're preferred. Choosing a more complicated function signature in order to remove a valid use of the `global` keyword makes about as much sense as writing complicated unreadable code rather than putting in one `GOTO` because *as everyone knows* GOTO is considered harmful ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith, any extension that requires different parameters passed to any function with globals in it. Say, guessing two words. This may not be evident now, but if it's needed later (when more code is already written), it's just going to be harder to re-factor. And is the alternative really complicated? OK, we can disagree.

Comment: @ReutSharabani trying to guess future use-cases is an exercise in futility. Hack out some code, get it working and maintainable. If your design document changes, hack out some more code and get it working and maintainable. Don't spend time trying to design code to be easily changed to meet some *FUTURE* design document the first time around :). However: agreed that this is getting off-topic. To each their own! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hangman game I had to make for the mitx intro to computer science a long time ago, you may find it useful and it shows how to make a game without the need for any global declaration:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase


def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    return all(x in letters_guessed for x in secret_word)


def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    return "".join([x for x in ascii_lowercase if x not in letters_guessed])


def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    return "".join([letter if letter in letters_guessed else "_" for letter in secret_word])


def hangman(secret_word):
    print "Welcome to the game Hangman!"
    print "I am thinking of a word that is {} letters long\n-----------".format(len(secret_word))
    guesses = 8
    letters_guessed = []
    missed_l = ''
    correct_l = ''
    while True:
        if is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
            print "Congratulations, you won!"
            break
        elif len(missed_l) == 8:
            print "Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was {}.".format(secret_word)
            break
        print "You have {} guesses left".format(guesses)
        print "Available Letters: {}".format(get_available_letters(letters_guessed))
        l = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ").lower()
        if l in letters_guessed:
            print "Oops! You've already guessed that letter: {}\n-----------".format(
                get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
        elif l in secret_word:
            letters_guessed.append(l)
            get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed)
            correct_l += l
            print( "Good guess: {}\n-----------".format(
                "".join([x if x in letters_guessed else "_" for x in secret_word])))
        elif l not in secret_word:
            letters_guessed.append(l)
            guesses -= 1
            print "Oops! That letter is not in my word: {}\n-----------".format(
                get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
            missed_l += l

hangman("foobar")
```